# Radius of convergence of power series (random variables)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, power-series

Let $z_n$ be a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables and let

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z_nx^n$$

be a random power series.

How to show that the radius of convergence is almost surely constant? How to show that if $z_n$ have normal distribution the radius of convergence is 1 with probability 1? Thanks!

Comment: Since you accepted the answer below, please explain why the step I mention in a comment, holds.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me as though the radius of convergence is almost surely $1$, regardless of whether the random variable is normal or not.

Appealing to the Cauchy root test for the radius of convergence, $R$, we have
\begin{align*}
R = 1/ ( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z_n|^{1/n} ).
\end{align*}
Using the fact that the $Z_n$ are independent and identically distributed we have
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z_n|^{1/n} = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z|^{1/n},
\end{align*}
where $Z$ has the same distribution as $Z_1$. But now for all $\omega \in \Omega$, the sample space $Z(\omega) < \infty$, so 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z(\omega)|^{1/n} = 1, \quad \forall \,\omega \in \Omega,
\end{align*}
Hence we have
$$\mathbf P\Big [\big \{ \omega \, \colon \,\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z(\omega)|^{1/n} = 1 \}\Big ] = P\big [\Omega \big] = 1,$$
which is to say that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z_n|^{1/n}$ converges to $1$ almost surely.

Comment: One (significant) problem with this solution is to justify the step: "Using the fact that the $Z_n$ are independent and identically distributed we have $\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z_n|^{1/n} = \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} |Z|^{1/n}$,
where $Z$ has the same distribution as $Z_1$." Why is that?